# Two Android targets with the same code base installed simultaneously

Tags: android, android-library, intentservice

Im trying to build two diffrent Android apps derived from the same code base using a library project.

The apps are using a intent service for various operations, however this seems to fail when I have two apps using the same code base installed simultaneously.

It seems as if only the first version of the app I install works, the second one don't seem to get the service to run.

Does anyone have any experience of this? How could this be solved?

EDIT:
These are the manifests

Base:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.codebase"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"></supports-screens>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon_launcher" android:label="CodeBase" android:process="@string/app_name" android:name="com.codebase.activity.Application" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:name="com.codenase.activity.MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService" android:process="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

</manifest>
```

Target 1:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"></supports-screens>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon_launcher" android:label="Target One" android:name="com.codebase.activity.Application" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:name="com.codebase.activity.MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService" android:process="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService" />

            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Target 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.trg2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"></supports-screens>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon_launcher" android:label="Target 2" android:name="com.codebase.activity.Application" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:name="com.codebase.activity.MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Most likely something is wrong in your manifest

Comment: What could it be. How can I name the service diffrently?

Comment: incorrect namespace perhaps. Difficult to say without anything to look at.

Comment: Please publish both manifest.xml

Comment: Cant see anything out of the ordinary. How do you call your service?? Any logcat errors?

Comment: No errors. The service works perfectly for the app installed first. It's a IntentService but It seems as only one instance is installed. But each app should run isolated from each other?

Comment: @johan, nothing which makes me suspect. However, do not set **process** and **debuggable**

Comment: @johan, the single *<* in target1 is a typo??

Comment: @sterfan Yes thats a typo. Removed process and debuggable, no difference though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no need to define intent-filter for the service in AndroidManifest.xml in this situation, the following definition is sufficient if you don't need provide additional access point from outside your app:

```
<service android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService"/>
```

Then using [public Intent (Context packageContext, Class cls)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) to start service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), UpdateService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Second, if you do need provide additional access point from outside your app, don't use the same action name in multiple app, as it will fool Android OS when try to pass the intent to the corresponding service (in case if you use [public Intent (String action)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29) to start your service):

Target 1:

```
<service android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService" android:process="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService.TARGET_1" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Target 2:

```
<service android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService" android:process="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.codebase.service.UpdateService.TARGET_2" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But if I dont declare any intent filter in the Library project it don't seem to launch the service. And If I specify TARGET_1 in target 1 the same things happend. The service is only called internally in the Android Library

Comment: How do you create your Intent? You should use public Intent (Context packageContext, Class cls) create intent and start service. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Will reward you with the bounty when possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have two versions of the same android app based on one code base as you do.

I don't have any problems. Both app have different package names

However, I ensure that both have the same (shared) userId. Maybe that is the trick

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

(By the way, when I remember right, the userId required to have a dot in between)

Comment: What do you mean by same user?

Comment: Specifying a user id is only useful if you want both apps to run in the same process. Not normally required unless they need to talk to each other. Only 2 apps can ever have the same user id. Attempts to install more than 2 will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have qualified your services correctly in the manifest.

e.g

if you had:

> Main Project package name = com.johan.p1
>
> Library Project package name = com.johan.library

Assuming your service is in the library project, your main project would define the service as:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.johan.p1"

     <service android:name="com.johan.library.MyServiceName" />

</manifest>
```